# SSH accesss between CentOS and Vmware installed Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, vmware, remote-desktop

How to use SSH remote access between my CentOS (Host) and VMWare installed Ubuntu?

Comment: This question is way too open to be answered. A good starting point for you would be `man ssh`

Comment: @mauro.stettler please . I need some answers. Even worked links are there. I really love them. I am running out of time. thats the main point.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @mauro.stettler how to start?

Comment: you type `ssh <username>@<destination ip>` to connect to `<destination ip>` as user `<username>`

Comment: where I can found this destination IP ?

Comment: That's the ip of the host where you want to connect to. For example if `ifconfig eth0` on the destination host tells you the ip is `192.168.1.10` then that's the destination ip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12254/discussion-between-richard-parker-and-mauro-stettler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the `sshd` daemon on the remote host by entering `service ssh start` as root user.

Then type as `ifconfig -a` in the system where you would like to access it from other systems in the network.

after finding the IP address , type as

```
ssh <usernameoftheremotesystem>@<Ip-address>
```

thats it.